# calculation at row level in the total matrice, powerbi desktop

Tags: sum, dax, powerbi-desktop, subtotal

I have a matrice:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsR1r.png)

with some product name, reference line, stock quantity of the product, model stock of the product in different wharehouse, the gap between stock quantity and model stock, and the model stock covery

the dax code for the gap is :

Abs(Case(([Stock Qty APAC] < [Model Stock APAC]); ([Stock Qty APAC] - [Model Stock APAC]); 0))

So in the total, there is a lot more of stock quantity than in model stock so there is no ecart at all, and i have a covery of 100%

How could i change my code for having a total which represents rows where the model stock is actually >of the stock quantity and where i have real stock covery ?

I'm desesperate with if for two days now, if someone can help me ‌‌

I tried to put 0 every time the stock quantity is > tothe model stock, but the problem is the same :

the calculation of the total is carried out at the level of the line so in this case, it is the stock model which is greater than the stock quantity and suddenly this one is displayed at 0, and I therefore have no difference